# numpy 2d argwhere range in a matrix where a(ij) = a(ji)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to find the row and column index in a 2d numpy array where the value lies in a range. 
Though I am able to accomplish this with the following code, I would like only one occurrence to be encountered in a matrix where a <sub>ij</sub> = a <sub>ji</sub>:

```
In [118]: test_arr = np.array([[1, 0.2, 0.04], 
     ...:        [0.2, 0.3, 0.06 ], 
     ...:        [0.04, 0.06, 0.09] 
     ...: ]) 
     ...:     

In [119]: test_arr                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[119]: 
array([[1.  , 0.2 , 0.04],
       [0.2 , 0.3 , 0.06],
       [0.04, 0.06, 0.09]])

In [120]: np.argwhere((test_arr==0.06))                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[120]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 1]])
```

Is there any way using `numpy` where we can restrict `i<j` so that the output will only be as:

```
array([[1, 2]])
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [38]: In [118]: test_arr = np.array([[1, 0.2, 0.04],  
    ...:      ...:        [0.2, 0.3, 0.06 ],  
    ...:      ...:        [0.04, 0.06, 0.09]  
    ...:      ...: ])                                                                                           
In [39]: test_arr                                                                                               
Out[39]: 
array([[1.  , 0.2 , 0.04],
       [0.2 , 0.3 , 0.06],
       [0.04, 0.06, 0.09]])
In [40]: np.where(test_arr==0.06)                                                                               
Out[40]: (array([1, 2]), array([2, 1]))
```

Let's explore using one of the `tri` functions to set some of the values of the array to 0:

```
In [41]: np.tril(test_arr)                                                                                      
Out[41]: 
array([[1.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.2 , 0.3 , 0.  ],
       [0.04, 0.06, 0.09]])
In [42]: np.triu(test_arr)                                                                                      
Out[42]: 
array([[1.  , 0.2 , 0.04],
       [0.  , 0.3 , 0.06],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.09]])
```

Now apply the equality test:

```
In [44]: np.triu(test_arr)==0.06                                                                                
Out[44]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False]])
In [45]: np.argwhere(np.triu(test_arr)==0.06)                                                                   
Out[45]: array([[1, 2]])
```

Comment: I am curious to know about the efficiency here as the test_arr is very very huge. Would ```result = np.argwhere((np.tril(test_arr) > 0.75) & (np.tril(test_arr) <= 0.99))``` be more efficient than 
```result = np.argwhere((test_arr > 0.75) & (test_arr <= 0.99)) for i,j in result: if i < j: print(i,j)``` ?

Comment: A faster way to filter `result` is `result[result[:,0] < result[:,1]]`